# Query and import range only returning header row

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to import a selection of columns if the text in a row is "Week 2." I'm having the issue that the query is only returning the header row. The formula I'm using is this:

=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eu5dJ5dOgFsG7jeIB1umoDOamt5r3BzYYoTWA1Rxyh0/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!A:Z"),"select Col5,Col7,Col8 where Col6='Week 2'",1)

I have some test sheets here:

Original where I'm importing info from: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eu5dJ5dOgFsG7jeIB1umoDOamt5r3BzYYoTWA1Rxyh0/edit#gid=0

Final destination (formula in A2): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19IC36izklxgId5zjtzr9HP71JYTrt_ReHBgxbAwBEpg/edit#gid=0

Comment: I'm open to using a filter formula or anything else. I just couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine, but you have the wrong column no.

```
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eu5dJ5dOgFsG7jeIB1umoDOamt5r3BzYYoTWA1Rxyh0/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!A:Z"),"select Col5,Col7,Col8 where Col6='Week 2'",1)
```

should be

```
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eu5dJ5dOgFsG7jeIB1umoDOamt5r3BzYYoTWA1Rxyh0/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!A:Z"),"select Col5,Col7,Col8 where Col5='Week 2'",1)
```

Comment: Check this reply if not already solved. I tested and seemed to work ok...